# Issue in rendering media files in django using mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, django-templates, mod-wsgi

I just came across an unique bug in my website which I have deployed in an apache webserver using mod_wsgi. The following is my apache conf file,

```
1 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
2
3 AliasMatch /([^/]*\.png) /var/www/mysite/media/photos/$1
4 AliasMatch /([^/]*\.gif) /var/www/mysite/media/photos/$1
5
6 AliasMatch /([^/]*\.gif) /var/www/mysite/media/admin/image/$1
7
8 <Directory /var/www/mysite/media>
9 Order deny,allow
10 Allow from all
11 </Directory>
12
13
14 <Directory /var/www/mysite/apache>
15 Order allow,deny
16 Allow from all
17 </Directory>
```

All the images and file are rendering perfectly expect for the .gif files inside /media/admin/images. As you can notice at line 4, I have already specified the .gif files which are displayed correctly.

If I put line 6 above line 4, line 4 will stop working and line 6 will be working. Why is it so? Is there any way in which I can overcome this, apart from making these files into a single directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is. You are saying to look in `/var/www/mysite/media/photos/` for every `.gif` file. If it is not there, it will fail. It will not go onto the second location to look. You either need to combine the folders, or have a different url for one of them. ex:

```
AliasMatch /admin/([^/]*\.gif) /var/www/mysite/media/admin/image/$1
```